# How to Hide Web View's Back Button from navigation bar in Initial Screen?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, back-button

I have `UIWebView` in my project and I want to hide right side button from initial view and display it when control goes to inside the link in the web view. This button is using for back navigation in a `UIWebView`.

Answer (score 0):

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
```

Comment: I have two back buttons 1 on left for navigating through screens and one on right side for navigation in web view. initially i want to hide web view's back button. When user click on link in web view then that button displays.

Comment: Please provide some code what you have deone. so I can help you

Answer (score 0):

Use the `UIWebViewDelegate` methods `webViewDidStartLoad:` or `webViewDidFinishLoad:`.  Once the delegate methods are called, you know that your web view is trying to load a new page.  When a new page has completely loaded, create a new `UIBarButtonItem` with the back action:

```
UIBarButtonItem *button = [UIBarButtonItem ...];
button.action = [webView goBack];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = button;
```

Then, if the webview cannot go back any further, hide or nil out the button.